# Equations for 2 variable Linear Regression

Tags: equation, regression, linear-regression

We are using a programming language that does not have a linear regression function in it. We have already implemented a single variable linear equation:

> y = Ax + B

and have simply calculated the A and B coefficents from the data using a solution similar to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364558/find-a-best-fit-equation#364585).

I know this problem gets geometrically harder as variables are added, but for our purposes, we only need to add one more:

> z = Ax + By + C

Does anyone have the closed form equations, or code in any language that can solve for A, B and C given an array of x, y, and z's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so you have three linear equations

```
k = aX1 + bY1 + cZ1
k = aX2 + bY2 + cZ2
k = aX3 + bY3 + cZ3
```

What you can do is rewrite it as matriz

```
| x1 y1 z1 | | a |   | k |
| x2 y2 z2 | | b | = | k |
| x3 y3 y3 | | c |   | k |
```

to work out `[a b c ]` do the following matrix operation

```
| a |              | x1 y1 z1 |     | k |
| b | =  inverse(  | x2 y2 z2 | )   | k |
| c |              | x3 y3 y3 |     | k |
```

The formula for a 3x3 matrix inverse can be found [here](http://www.dr-lex.be/random/matrix_inv.html)

Comment: If you have more than three points, this method won't work.  The least squares solution minimizes the error for more than three points.

Comment: No duffymo. This is correct and works to solve a 2 variable linear regression. See the example at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression where the X matrix is 15 rows by 3 columns. It gets multiplied by its transpose and thus creates a 3x3 matrix that needs to be inverted

Comment: I do realize that hhafez did answer this to solve simultaneous linear equations rather than my linear regression problem. But, none-the-less, it did lead me to the 3x3 matrix inverse equations, which is what I really needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's an easy linear algebra problem if you think of it the way [Gil Strang](http://videolectures.net/mit18085f07_strang_lec04/) does it.  [Here's](http://www.dm.unibo.it/~regonati/ad0708/strang-FTLA.pdf) a written explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use MatLab or does the calculation have to occur inside your software?

MatLab instructions on [multiple regression analysis](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/data_analysis/f1-8450.html).

[Integrating MatLab with C#](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12987).

Comment: No. It's got to be inside a third-party language we are using, which has no hooks to the outside world.